# using progressbar with AsyncTask

Tags: android, file, android-asynctask, download

I implemented code to download file from url which is working fine(I am using asynctask to download file).

Now I want to add progressbar to the download, I went through some threads and found that i need to implement `protected void onPreExecute()` & `protected void onPostExecute()`. I did the first part. how can I implement the `protected void onPostExecute()` with my example.

my full mainactivity is as below

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private ProgressDialog pdia;
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        public void download(View v)
        {
            Log.i("download...", "download");
            new DownloadFile().execute("http://10.0.2.2/filedemo/file1.pdf", "myfile1.pdf"); 
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){ 
           super.onPreExecute();
                    pdia = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
                    pdia.setMessage("Downloading...");
                    pdia.show(); 

        }   

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String fileUrl = strings[0];   // -> url to file
            String fileName = strings[1];  // -> myfile.pdf
            String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File folder = new File(extStorageDirectory, "myapplication");
            folder.mkdir();

            File pdfFile = new File(folder, fileName);

            try{
                pdfFile.createNewFile();
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            FileDownloader.downloadFile(fileUrl, pdfFile);
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            //called on ui thread
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (pdia != null) {
                        pdia.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });


            }  
    }   
 }
```

thank you...

Comment: Check the official docs? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: what problem getting with current code?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK problem is not there but i didnt knew how to add it

Comment: If you actually want a `ProgressBar` then you most likely want to use `publishProgress()` in `doInBackground()` and implement `onProgressUdpate()`

Comment: @codeMagic checking for new so threads relative to this.

Comment: The link at the top has an example of someone doing it. Check that

Answer (score 1):

The result you return from `doInBackground` is passed to `onPostExecute`. Since you return `null`, you can just dismiss the dialog in onPostExecute:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
//called on ui thread
            if (pdia != null) {
                pdia.dismiss();
            }

}
```

Comment: should i use `runonuithread()` method or any other thing, bit new to asynctask

Comment: No. You don't need to. onPostExecute is called on UI Thread so you don't need to use runonuithread(). I added the comment to help you

Answer (score 0):

You can check [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) an API to use a progress bar and [here](http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/android/android-asynctask-example-download-progress/) a good example.

Comment: had checked it out already, but example there uses handleer

Comment: Sorry... i change the example in my answer. Try this example... is very simple.